# RequireJS dependency script is loading but not accessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

First time using RequireJS.  Had some code working, but now it's not.

1. Including `require.js` by itself in `index.html` like so.

   ```
   <script data-main="scripts/main" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
   ```
2. `main.js` provides paths, shims, and points to `app.js`

   ```
   require.config({
   paths: {
       jQuery: "libs/jquery-2.0.3.min",
       kendo: "libs/kendo.mobile.min",
       Parse: "libs/parse-1.2.16.min"
   },
   shim: {
       jQuery: {
           exports: "jQuery"
       },
       kendo: {
           deps: [ "jQuery" ],
           exports: "kendo"
       },
       Parse: {
           exports: "Parse"
       }
   }
     });

   var app;

   require([ "app/app" ], function(application) {
       app = application, app.init();
   });;
   ```
3. `app.js`

   ```
   define(["jQuery", "kendo", "Parse", "app/utils", "app/config"], function ($, kendo, Parse, utils, config) {

   var _onError = function (error, url, line) {
       utils.showError(error);
   };

   var init = function () {

       var kendoApp = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
           // options
       });

       Parse.initialize(config.parseAppId, config.parseJSKey);

       console.log('test1');
       utils.init(kendoApp);

   };

   return {
       config: config,
       init: init,
       // others
   }
   });
   ```
4. but utils.init doesn't fire.

   ```
   define([], function() {

   console.log('test3');
   var _kendoApp;
   return {
       init: function(kendoApp) {
           _kendoApp = kendoApp;
           console.log('test2');
       },
   ```

Result: I see "test1", but not "test2" or "test3".  utils.js is being loaded (200 status OK in headers).

Comment: Could you show your main.js file?

Comment: @AndreyShustariov, edited. Put it under #2

Comment: It is quite strange: I expected to see 'test3' before 'test1'. Could you check, what is ```typeof``` utils in your **app.js**?

Comment: Just to confirm, the way you've pasted your utils file is not the full version, correct?  Otherwise, it is not closed off correctly

Comment: @AndreyShustariov, typeof(utils) is object, and it even has init assigned to an anonymous function! blarg. maybe console.log is someone supressed

Comment: @Tom, yea you're right it's truncated. As far as I can tell utils looks good (is properly closed off).  No errors thrown.